# Symfony4 : ./node_modules/.bin/encore: No such file or directory

Tags: webpack, vagrant, symfony4, webpack-encore

I try to use webpack to generate assets on Symfony4

I started by adding it using yarn :

```
yarn add @symfony/webpack-encore --dev
```

On the installation I get this error

> error An unexpected error occurred: "EPROTO: protocol error, symlink
>   '../../../parser/bin/babel-parser.js' ->
>   '/home/vagrant/Symfony/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/.bin/parser'".

After a search on the net, I found that the solution is by adding `--no-bin-links`, so I try it and the installation ended without any error.

but when I want to generate the assets by this command

```
./node_modules/.bin/encore dev
```

I get this error (.bin folder not found)

> -bash: ./node_modules/.bin/encore: No such file or directory

and when I try to use this command `yarn encore dev` or `yarn run encore dev`

> error Command "encore" not found.

I searched a lot on the net, but nothing works, is there any solution to fix this problem ?

**PS :** I use Vagrant and Homestead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed by editing the `scripts` on package.json by :

```
"scripts": {
        "dev-server": "./node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/bin/encore.js dev-server",
        "dev": "./node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/bin/encore.js dev",
        "watch": "./node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/bin/encore.js dev --watch",
        "build": "./node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/bin/encore.js production"
    }
```

and I use this command to generate the assets `yarn run dev`

Answer (score 0):

Either use **yarn 1.12.1** or install the packages with **npm**.

It's an issue with yarn, [source](https://github.com/camacho/install-deps-postmerge/issues/1), [issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6844).

Comment: I try to install it with different version of yarn and by npm, but always I get the error